# Custom WP_list_table alternating row colors in WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Friends,

I implemented a class that extends WP_List_Table, and I use the function single_row to override the styles of the rows based on their contents. My code is here:

```
public function single_row( $item ) {
    $row_class = ($item['status'] == 'submitted') ? '#b2dfbc' : '#ffe9a6';
    echo '<tr bgcolor="'.$row_class.'">';
    $this->single_row_columns( $item );
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Based on the 'status' field, I'm using either '#b2dfbc' or '#ffe9a6' as a background color. However, the issue arises from WP_List_Table's default utilization of alternating row colors. While my code successfully overwrites the background color for even rows, it does not affect odd rows. Upon inspecting the rendered HTML, I noticed that there is a stylesheet that overrides my background color settings for odd rows.

```
.alternate,.striped>tbody>:nth-child(odd),ul.striped>:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f6f7f7;
}
```

How can I set my preferred background color for odd rows? Adding !important rule doesn't help. Additionally, could you suggest how to control the background color of odd and even rows separately in the single_row function if I want to maintain the alternating coloring?

Thanks!

Comment: _"Adding !important rule doesn't help."_ - not sure what you'd want to add `!important` to here in the first place - when you are setting the background color via the `bgcolor` _HTML attribute_ ...? If you stopped doing that, and instead actually added _classes_ on the TR elements, then you could write rules targeting those, and had something that you could use !important on (or increase the specificity of, in comparison to the existing rules.)